# Voltage applied to secondary is not matching calculation

Tags: circuit-analysis

Why is the RMS voltage applied to the secondary not 3.3 V in Multisim? 120/36 = 3.3 V
[image: circuit]

Comment: Where is  the reference point for your voltmeter?

Comment: Diode drop assuming the measurement is referenced to the ground symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked this twice now with all due respect. Look at where your ground is. You're measuring between the peak of the AC input to the rectifier and the grounded negative DC output rail of the rectifier. Try measuring across the transformer secondary and see what you get.